# Get error "Class name (...) doesnt match path (...)" when trying to load library

Tags: android, android-studio, intellij-idea, android-library

I have build a library, I have tried to load it (I have added the module to the sample app -> android gradle -> dependency), but when I compile the sample app, this is give me this error 16 times (every error have another file - anim/attrs/layout/id....):

> Error:Gradle: com.android.dx.cf.iface.ParseException: class name
>   (com/cld/ui/lib/R$anim) does not match path
>   (com/cld/UI/lib/R$anim.class)

this is the project file structure:
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just read the error message: one case you have `ui` and the second one, `UI`. This is not the same thing. Put `ui` in uppercase.

Comment: Its partially worked. There is the same error about the BuildConfig which is still appears. Where is this file exists and How can I change his package from ui to UI?Thanks

Comment: You created the library right? Check all your paths and names, for example in your samples and in your lib folder you have UI and ui. try to always use UI to be sure to get rid of this problem.

Comment: I have searched for "ui", found that the package in BuildConfig.class used ui and not UI. changed it, cleaned project, and it still writing the error about this file. Any idea?

Comment: OK, after rebuild project, its working, thanks for you help